# Delay in opening of fragment when click on item and we move another activity containing fragments of android in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-activity

I am moving from one activity to another containing 6 more fragments in that activity , I have used navhost for it but it is delaying the transaction. Activity is opening late. the Image has layout. In my view that circular bar that i customized is creating issue.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iW46X.jpg)

Comment: Please, consider adding your code where this delay is present. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask follow this guide and try to update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

i think you must handling `image src` in your fragment not ui fragment